# Django function execution

Tags: django, python-3.x, function

In views, I have a function defined which is executed when the user submits the form online. After the form submission there are some database transactions that I perform and then based on the existing data in the database API's are triggered:

```
triggerapi():
   execute API to send Email to the user and the administrator about 
   the submitted form
def databasetransactions():
    check the data in the submitted form with the data in DB
    if the last data submitted by the user is before 10 mins or more: 
       triggerapi()
def formsubmitted(request):
    save the user input in variables
    Databasetransactions()
    save the data from the submitted form in the DB
```

In the above case, the user clicks on submit button 2 times in less than 5 milliseond duration. So 2 parallel data starts to process and both trigger Email which is not the desired behavior.

Is there a way to avoid this ? So that for a user session, the application should only accept the data once all the older data processing is completed ?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking in pseudo-code, one way could be to use a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for `triggerapi()` and return [Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) in case it is already istantiated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue. 
One of them would be to create a new session variable
`request.session['activetransaction'] = True`
This would however require you to pass request, unless it is already passed and we got a changed code portion. You can also add an instance/ class flag for it in the same way and check with it.
Another way, which might work if you need those submissions handled after the previous one, you can always add a `while request.session['activetransaction']:` and do the handling afterwards.

```
def formsubmitted(request):
    if 'activetransaction' not in request.session or not request.session['activetransaction']:
        request.session['activetransaction'] = True
        # save the user input in variables
        Databasetransactions()
        # save the data from the submitted form in the DB
        request.session['activetransaction'] = False
    ...
```